# Ionic 2 not running on Android device after aws-setup

Tags: android, typescript, angular, aws-sdk, ionic2

I'm developing an Typescript/Angular 2/Ionic 2 mobile app.

This app must use Amazon SNS together GCM to send and receive push messages.

One of the steps is to install aws-sdk. Aws-sdk was installed from npm and the declarations files was installed via DefinitelyTyped.

The app works well in the Android emulator (*$ ionic run android -s -c -l --stacktrace --emulator --debug*), but in a Android device (*ionic run android -s -c -l --stacktrace --device --debug*) it crashes.

It give this message in device screen:

> Application Error
>
> Connection to the server was unsuccessful. (ionic server ip and port
>   here)

In terminal it shows the following message:

```
 0     318710   log      deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. 
 1     318757   log      Channel not fired: onPluginsReady 
 2     318764   log      Channel not fired: onCordovaReady 
 3     318771   log      Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
```

Edit:
It seem related to phonegap push plugin + livereload. When I run without live reload it not crashes.

Comment: Isn't this a CORS problem? Did you set up your proxies correctly and disabled them on native?

Comment: Not a CORS problem. I think its related to  phonegap push plugin + livereload.